# Integral convergence/divergence

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I'm a bit struggled with this integral. I need to prove whether this integral converges or diverges.$$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^p+x^q}$$ here $p>q$. I do know, that I need to divide this interal into two parts: $$\int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{x^p+x^q} + \int_{1}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^p+x^q}$$ What equivalent function can I take instead of $\frac{1}{x^p+x^q}$ ?

Comment: $\frac{C}{x^q}$ close to the origin, $\frac{D}{x^p}$ close to $+\infty$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you very much! That helped me a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. As soon as you have enough reputation (I guess I am contributing by upvoting your question) you may upvote/accept (through the grey up-arrow/the green tick) answers.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid integrability issues in a right neighbourhood of the origin we need $q<1$ and in order to avoid integrability issues in a left neighbourhood of $+\infty$ we need $p>1$. If such constraints holds, the value of the integral is given by 
$$ \frac{\pi}{(p-q)\sin\left(\frac{\pi(1-q)}{p-q}\right)}$$
due to [Euler's Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: I believe you're telling truth, but in my case I need to show it as simple, as I can - no Euler's Beta function, no reflection formula for the Γ function at all. I have to show it by simple equivalent functions.

Comment: @JonasVitkauskas: then just ignore the last part of my answer. $q<1$ and $p>1$ are both sufficient and necessary conditions for the integrability over $\mathbb{R}^+$, since the integrand function behaves like $\frac{1}{x^q}$ close to the origin and like $\frac{1}{x^p}$ for large values of $x$.